# Add Image Texture to a Cone

Tags: texturing, materials

I would like to create a party hat and skip the part where I manually add materials, instead I planned to add image textures. The problem is When I try to add a texture it does not show properly. This has been my 3rd question this week. Thank you very much for those who have answered my previous 2 questions I am learning Blender step by step with your help :)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as you are using cycles, You need to create a new material and head over to the node page. SHIFT_A and add an image texture. Find your image texture and make sure you assign your object through edit mode to the material you have chosen. NOw in edit mode press u and then click Smart UV Unwrap. If that looks funny just do U and unwrap.
Gl

Comment: I did what you taught me. And it worked my problem is the image texture i added does not show when i try to render D:

Edit: Nevermind i worked hehe Thank you very much